# How can a JavaScript function parameter be used in the function body as a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, parameter-passing

My JavaScript function is called by several CGI scripts, and thus I would like to pass the script-specific HTML id attribute as an argument to my function. Then, in the function body, I would like to use the parameter holding this argument in the jQuery shortcut. However, my parameter keeps getting interpreted as a string literal when I use the jQuery syntax.

Writing out the long-form JavaScript to use the parameter works, but because I use the jQuery shortcut everywhere else, I would like to use the same syntax for this case as well. Each page can have multiple tables, so selecting on the table element will not work. I cannot find any documentation for what I am trying to accomplish. In Perl, this would be similar to using ${parameter_name} instead of $parameter_name.

deleteItem.cgi (Perl):

```
my $rows;
my $counter = 0;
for (@array) {
  $rows .= "
    <tr id='del$counter' class='bg-dark' onclick='setRowBackground(\'deleteItems\', $counter)'>
      <td>$_</td>
    </tr>
  ";
  $counter++;
}

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="setBackground.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="deleteItems" class="bg-dark">
    $rows
  </table>
</body>
```

setBackground.js:

```
$(function() {
  // this uses the id name and is what I am trying to avoid so that
  setBackground.js can be used by multiple CGI scripts //
  $('#deleteItems').DataTable();
});

function setRowBackground(tableID, rowNumber) {
  // after removing class "bg-dark"
  none of these work: //
  $("#tableID").DataTable().row(rowNumber).nodes().to$().addClass("bg-white");
  $(#"tableID").DataTable().row(rowNumber).nodes().to$().addClass("bg-white");
  $(#tableID).DataTable().row(rowNumber).nodes().to$().addClass("bg-white");
  $(#(tableID)).DataTable().row(rowNumber).nodes().to$().addClass("bg-white");

  // these do work:
  ...but this one can only be used for a table with this id, and table ids
  are not consistent accross multiple CGI scripts! //
  $(#deleteItems).DataTable().row(rowNumber).nodes().to$().addClass("bg-white");
  // ...but this one is what I am trying to avoid since the rest of the code
  uses jQuery. //
  document.getElementById(tableId).DataTable().row(rowNumber).nodes().to$().addClass("bg-white");
}
```

Comment: `$("#tableID")` should be `$("#" + tableID)`. Variables aren't expanded inside strings, you need to concatenate them.

Comment: Excellent, Barmar! It worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#" + tableID)`

Thank you, [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) for the solution! Concatenation did not occur to me.